# Get 404 Not Found with PUT request in MEAN app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I have an Edit button on my event-detail page that goes to a new page where user can update the current selected event. I have no trouble using GET to get single/all events and POST to create new event. But I'm stuck on updating existing event and constantly get 404 error: PUT http://localhost:3000/api/events 404 (Not Found)
On my server route I have:

```js
//return event-details
app.get('/api/events/:id', events.getEventById);

//update event
app.put('/api/events/:id', events.updateCurrentEvent);
```

Server side event controller:

```js
exports.updateCurrentEvent = function(req, res) {

     Event.findById(req.params.id, req.body, function(err, event) {
        var event = req.body;
        if(!event) {
            res.statusCode = 404;
            res.send({ error: 'Not found'});
        }
        event.title = req.body.title;
        event.desc = req.body.desc;
        event.date = req.body.date;
        event.duration = req.body.duration;
        event.address = req.body.address;
        event.city = req.body.city;
        event.state = req.body.state;

        event.save(function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                log.info("event updated");
                res.send({ status: 'OK', event:event });
            } else {
                if(err.name == 'ValidationError') {
                    res.statusCode = 400;
                    res.send({ error: 'Validation error' });
                } else {
                    res.statusCode = 500;
                    res.send({ error: 'Server error' });
                }
                log.error('Internal error(%d): %s',res.statusCode,err.message);
            }
        });

    });
```

My $resource service:

```js
app.factory('mvEvent', function($resource) {
    var EventResource = $resource('/api/events/:_id', {_id: "@id"}, {
        update: {method:'PUT', isArray:false}
    });

    return EventResource;
});
```

my client-side controller:

```js
angular.module('app').controller('mvUpdateEventCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, $location, mvEvent) {

    $scope.event = mvEvent.get({_id:$routeParams.id})
        .$promise
            .then(function(event) {
                $scope.event = event;
                console.log($scope.event);
                $scope.title =$scope.event.title;
                $scope.desc = $scope.event.desc;
                $scope.date = $scope.event.date;
                $scope.duration = $scope.event.duration;
                $scope.address = $scope.event.address;
                $scope.city = $scope.event.city;
                $scope.state = $scope.event.state;
            });

    $scope.updateEvent = function() {
        $scope.event.$update(function() {
        }, function(error) {
            $scope.error = error.data.message;
        });
    }
});
```

My client side routes:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
        //events route
        .when('/events', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/events/event-list',
            controller: 'mvEventListCtrl'
        })
        //events detail route
        .when('/events/:id', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/events/event-details',
            controller: 'mvEventDetailsCtrl'
        })
        //update event route
        .when('/events/:id/update', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/admin/event-update',
            controller: 'mvUpdateEventCtrl'
        })
});
```

Getting the event details showing in the each text field is as far as I can get. As soon as I hit 'Update event' Button I get 404 error and it seems to lie somewhere in my server side code. I've seen quite a bit of different approaches implementing PUT request, with or without routeParams, using findById then save or findByIdAndUpdate. I'm wondering if there is a standard way to do this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! spend some time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question to understand how to ask a quality question.

Comment: can you post how the url is looking into the browser console ?

Comment: The promise of get(event._id) is logged in the console when update event page is loaded. But I get 'PUT /api/events 404 not found' after update event button is hit.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `var event = req.body;` from your server side controller. Firstly, it is not required. Secondly, it is same as the name of the document returned by `Event.findById` callback, and that's getting overridden by the variable declaration.

```
 exports.updateCurrentEvent = function(req, res) {

     Event.findById(req.params.id, req.body, function(err, event) {

        var event = req.body;  // <<==== Remove this line

        if(!event) {
            res.statusCode = 404;
            res.send({ error: 'Not found'});
        }

        event.title = req.body.title;
        event.desc = req.body.desc;
        event.date = req.body.date;
        event.duration = req.body.duration;
        event.address = req.body.address;
        event.city = req.body.city;
        event.state = req.body.state;

        event.save(function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                log.info("event updated");
                res.send({ status: 'OK', event:event });
            } else {
                if(err.name == 'ValidationError') {
                    res.statusCode = 400;
                    res.send({ error: 'Validation error' });
                } else {
                    res.statusCode = 500;
                    res.send({ error: 'Server error' });
                }
                log.error('Internal error(%d): %s',res.statusCode,err.message);
            }
        });
    });
}
```